# json parsing in python with condition

Tags: python, json

Could you give me some advice about parsing list from list of dictionary with some conditions in Python3.

From below list of json, I want to extract the max timestamp for each "id".

So the final output I want to have is like

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "value": {
        "val1": 400000000,
        "val2": 750000000
    },
    "timestamp": 1600957822.2510917
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "value": {
        "val1": 400000000,
        "val2": 750000000
    },
    "timestamp": 1600958083.618805
}]
```

Is there any way I can do? Thanks in advance

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "value": {
        "val1": 400000000,
        "val2": 750000000
    },
    "timestamp": 1600957822.2510917
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "value": {
        "val1": 400000000,
        "val2": 750000000
    },
    "timestamp": 1600957857.3018847
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "value": {
        "val1": 400000000,
        "val2": 750000000
    },
    "timestamp": 1600958027.4114041
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "value": {
        "val1": 400000000,
        "val2": 750000000
    },
    "timestamp": 1600958083.618805
}]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, it's just looping through a list of dictionaries. The fact that the list came from parsing JSON is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If it's list of dictionaries (as spotted in the comments) here is a way to parse it and retrieve a final list of dict:

```
result = {}
for obj in dict_list:
    if obj['id'] in result:
        if result[obj['id']]['timestamp'] < obj['timestamp']:
            result[obj['id']]['timestamp'] = obj['timestamp']
    else:
        result[obj['id']] = obj
[x for x in result.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of parsing:

```
import json

# load json
data = json.loads(source)

result = {}

# iterate over json objects
for d in data:
    # check whether id is already in result map or not
    if d['id'] in result:
        # if id already in result, compare timestamps
        if d['timestamp'] > result[d['id']]:
            result[d['id']] = d['timestamp']
    else:
        # if id not in result, add id / timestamp pair
        result[d['id']] = d['timestamp']
    
print (result)
```